# Efficient Binary Streaming

Tags: c++

I'm looking to stream blocks of 16-bit integers into a program. (Could be from a file or standard input, whatever.) Being as concise as possible, my starting point counts the octets input into the program:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int16_t samples[768];
    while (std::cin.good()) {
        std::cin.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(samples), sizeof(samples));
        if (std::cin.gcount() == sizeof(samples)) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    assert(std::cin.eof());
    return 0;
}
```

While this works, I want to make sure I'm not missing some more C++ method of performing the same function. (Create a std::vector and read directly into its memory space?) This is supposed to be efficient so I assume that reading a single 16-bit integer at a time and appending to a vector would be out of the question.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would use `<unistd.h>`'s `read` to read into buffer, which can be pointer to a pre-allocated std::vector. That way, you won't be moving data around.

Comment: @eudoxos Just as `istream::read` can.

Answer (score 0):

The code as written should read an array of 16 bit values. The only problem is that it assumes that the byte order the file was written with is the same byte order as is used where it is read. Whether this is the case isn't clear from the question. In cases where files are exchanged e.g. between x86 and Sparc machines you it is common to choose *network byte order* and to process the values with `ntohs()` when reading (and `htons()` when writing). Although these look like functions they are typically just macros which don't do anything to the value on platforms using network byte order.

Comment: Or use one of the `_swab` style functions, which works on a whole block of values at once.  Either way, use block reads for the I/O and do the byte swapping afterwards, don't read individual elements and byte swap.